# ESP8266 Aes encryption using Arduino IDE

Tags: esp8266, library, communication

I'm trying to implement an AES encryption function on my ESP8266 controller, using Arduino ide and [this aes library](https://github.com/spaniakos/AES/).
I finally made it work after many attempts but the output i get from the encryption function is only numerical and it doesn't correspond to other encryptions made by other softwares.

This is the code part relative to the AES encryption:

```
 #include <AES.h>

AES aes ;
byte *key = (unsigned char*)"0123456789010123";
unsigned long long int my_iv = 36753562;
 tempToken = RANDOM_REG32 % 10000;
    randomstr = String(tempToken);
    //answer = "{\"token\":\"" + randomstr + "\"}";
    byte plain[4];
    randomstr.getBytes(plain, 4);
    Serial.println(randomstr);
    Serial.println(plain[0]);
    Serial.println(plain[1]);
    Serial.println(plain[2]);
    Serial.println(plain[3]);
    byte cipher [48];
  //  aes.iv_inc();
    byte iv [N_BLOCK] ;
    aes.set_IV(my_iv);
    aes.do_aes_encrypt(plain, 48, cipher, key, 128, iv);
    String ciphertoken = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
      ciphertoken += cipher[i];
    }
    answer = "{\"token\":\"" + ciphertoken + "\"}";
```

It basically generates a random number between 0 - 9999, then converts it in a byte array (because aes function needs a byte array as input), then encrypt this byte array and prints the output, written in `cipher` byte array.

This is the output I get from it

```
6188
54
49
56
0
{"token":"521111513725521540120674957151112223103194250224197251261938514437131212302201813929189123134524113912554682501508415421130220"}
```

I can't understand if I did something wrong of if it is formatted in a strange way and if I can get the right encryption from it

Comment: Could you replace your code with a minimal, complete and verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please (remove the random part - use a well-defined input for this purpose), as well as the output you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this is the only problem, but the way you are building up the string is bad: you are appending the decimal value of each byte of the cipher - so if your cipher array were, say, `{ 0x52, 0x11, 0x115, 0x137, 0x255, 0x215, 0x40, 0x1, 0x20 .... }` you'd get the string you're getting: `521111513725521540120...`  That's probably not what you want.

Probably what you want for that part is to base64-encode `cipher`, which you can find out how to do, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180947/base64-decode-snippet-in-c).  (If you see encrypted stuff in printable format, usually it's base64 encoded.)